# Vim and Quickfix - Double output - rails.vim help needed

Tags: vim, terminal, zsh, rails.vim

I have used Vim for 2 days now - so I'm a newbie. I'm really stuck on this problem.

When I run some commands the output is displayed twice: first in the terminal, and the in the Quickfix window (is it called that?).

For example: I type ':make'. It looks like Vim closes. Then there's some output listed. I hit 'Enter'. The output is listed again in the Quickfix window. I hit 'Enter' again.

For rails.vim I type ':Rgenerate model person name'. It looks like Vim closes. Then there's some output listed. I hit 'Enter'. And I'm back in Vim. I would like Vim to list the output in the Quickfix window, of course.

Commands like ':ls' works just fine - it lists the output fine in the Quickfix window.

I have made a video of the problem and posted it on YouTube: http://youtu.be/KvmulO4L4hc

About my setup:

- I am using Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)
- I am not using MacVim
- I have installed Vim using Homebrew (using https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/vim.rb)
- I am using Zsh (with oh-my-zsh)
- I'm using pathogen.vim to install my plugins (I have only installed rails.vim and NERDTree)

My ~/.vimrc file looks like this:

```
" pathogen.vim
call pathogen#infect()

" Settings
set shell=/bin/sh
set expandtab shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2 tabstop=2
set autoindent
set number numberwidth=5
set backspace=start,eol,indent
set noswapfile

" Colors
colorscheme railscasts
syntax on

" Remove all trailing whitespace on save
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e

" Unmap arrow keys
nnoremap <Left> :echoe "Use h"<CR>
nnoremap <Right> :echoe "Use l"<CR>
nnoremap <Up> :echoe "Use k"<CR>
nnoremap <Down> :echoe "Use j"<CR>
```

My ~/.zshrc file looks like this:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh configuration.
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="highcode"

# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set to this to use case-sensitive completion
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Comment this out to disable weekly auto-update checks
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable colors in ls
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable autosetting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want red dots to be displayed while waiting for completion
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# Homebrew
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

# rbenv
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

I hope you can help me!

Cheers! :-)

Comment: That's Vim's normal behaviour in the terminal: it's unable to run commands asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know it's unable to run commands asynchronously. In http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30P8DSNOZuU he uses an ":!" command  like ":!ruby ..." But the output goes to his Quickfix window... and not the terminal itself (where it looks like it closes Vim). Is this a Vim setting to make output go to the Quickfix window?

Comment: This is not the quickfix window: only the command line expanding to show the output of the external command. You open the quickfix window with `:copen` (which actually contains the output of `make`). In your link, it looks like he is using GVim, not CLI Vim, hence the difference in behaviour.

Comment: @romainl Thank you! Installing MacVim solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592222/vim-and-quickfix-double-output-rails-vim-help-needed#comment13726697_10592222) from romainl above:

> This is not the quickfix window: only the command line expanding to show the output of the external command. You open the quickfix window with :copen (which actually contains the output of make). In your link, it looks like he is using GVim, not CLI Vim, hence the difference in behaviour.